# JSF Combobox populated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, combobox

I am new to JSF, so please bear with me.
I have a datatable containing many columns,it has a column having all comboboxes with same set of select values for each. User select value in first combobox and click on a button 'Fill Down' which copies its values to all combo boxes below that column using Javascript.

My Javascript is able to populate values into all the comboxes text boxes, but they are not getting saved in backing bean. Also, after populating values using javascript if I look at 'view source' , there are old values in comboboxField textbox (which is created automatically at backend by JSF). For other textboxes backing bean is popukated using same JS.

Complete datatable(comboxes,textboxes)  are rendered Dynamically using java code,Thanks to BaluC articles, I am using JSF 1.2 & Richfaces 3.3.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: I believe you're confusing "combobox" with "dropdownlist". This problem is typical to dropdownlists (with fixed list values), not to comboboxes (with editable list values).

Comment: Thanks BaluC for replying, I have used HTMLComboBox in my code which generates a textbox with 'comboboxField' & button during rendering.
It's values are also populated using a List. I have tried setting those elements enabled,not readonly but still values are not binding but visually it shows new values in those textboxes. Is there any alternative field for combobox which does not give this issue.

Comment: any comments on this? How can I populate richfaces combobox value from javascript and then bind them with backing bean.

Comment: The issue is fixed.There is a hidden field 'id:comboboxValue' which gets populated as part of rendering.I populated that hidden field with javascript and values are binded now.